# Multiple templates for post/custom-post in elementor

Tags: wordpress, templates, custom-post-type, elementor

I need to render a single post differently under different paths(or even add a ?template type=value to use dynamically). Is that possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Elementor Pro you can achieve that by creating a single post template based on categories/tags.

You can look it up here: [How to Create a WordPress Single-Post Template in Elementor](https://elementor.com/blog/design-your-single-post-template/)